# Trouble converting binary string to ASCII

Tags: c++, string

The program is supposed to take in a binary 8 bit number string, and then output the respective letters for the binary entered.  For example, if `0110100001100101011011000110110001101111` was types in, the program should output `hello`.  I have no idea where to start, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"I have no idea where to start"*.  How about starting with `int main()`, and reading some input?   After that, you can worry about processing the input.

Comment: Is your issue with reading characters?  Is your issue with converting binary?  Is your issue outputting characters?  Do you know how to write a simple program?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
loop
    read eight 1/0 characters from stdin into a string
    if read failed due to EOF
        break out of loop
    convert 8 character binary string to equivalent printable character
    output character to stdout
end
```

Start by implementing the loop itself, then add the code for input, then the conversion code and finally the output code. At each stage make sure that what you have implemented so far is working correctly. By breaking the problem down into a series of smaller simpler operations you can see that the whole task becomes a lot easier to approach.